# Integral beginner proof

Tags: integration, analysis

**Question:**

Let $f:[0,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  be a continuous function. Show that, if $$\int\limits_0^{\pi} f(t)\sin(t)dt =0,$$ then the equation $f(x)=0$ admits a solution in $[0,\pi].$

**What I've thought of:**

I'd suppose that $f(x) > 0$ and try to get a contradiction, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

I'm still new to integrals and would appreciate if someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in [0, \pi]$, then we have $f(x)\sin(x)>0$ for all $x\in (0, \pi)$, and therefore we have
$$
\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(x)dx > 0
$$
Similarly for $f(x)<0$ for all $x$.

So by contraposition, there must be some $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)\leq0$ and some $x_2$ such that $f(x_2)\geq0$. If any of these two are equalities, we are done. If neither is an equality, the intermediate value theorem says there is some $x_3$ between them with $f(x_3)=0$.

Comment: it would be good to add that these are the only two possibilities by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. In $(0,\pi)$

$$f(x)>0\implies f(x)\sin(x)>0\implies\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(x)\,dx>0,$$ a contradiction.